# Getting error "Object doesn't support property or method 'commitPopup'" when saving a new alert in SP 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, iframe

In my SP 2010 environment, I have a html page, that has an iframe, and the iframe is the page where you create a new alert for a list. In the html page, I dynamically create the iframe and then insert some script nodes in it to run jquery in the alert page.

The problem is, when I click the save button, I get the error message

```
Line: 1
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'commitPopup'
```

coming from this line (which is the iframe source page)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();<
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [TechNet forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/77f3eb89-1596-4621-a483-ab57647fd48a/windowframeelementcommitpopup-not-working) recommends using

Check in your modal dialog code are you missing the below statement that handle closing the dialog

```
window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'text');
```

or

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1,'text')
```